# c# OdataClient: DataServiceActionQuery, how to execute a function Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central?

Tags: c#, odata, nav, dynamics-business-central, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I've been trying to run a NAV function (Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central) from microsoft's odata client. when I create an odatav4 data source, and import the **$metadata**, I was able to include the codeunits functions in the autogenerated code, this creates a DataServiceActionQuery types for me:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// There are no comments for Funcions_TestFunction in the schema.
 /// </summary>
 [global::Microsoft.OData.Client.OriginalNameAttribute("Funcions_TestFunction")]
 public virtual global::Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceActionQuery Funcions_TestFunction(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        return new global::Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceActionQuery(this, this.BaseUri.OriginalString.Trim('/') + "/Funcions_TestFunction", new global::Microsoft.OData.Client.BodyOperationParameter("param1", param1),
                new global::Microsoft.OData.Client.BodyOperationParameter("param2", param2),
                new global::Microsoft.OData.Client.BodyOperationParameter("param3", param3));
    }
```

when I try to run it, I have to pass the company code to it, but I don't know how to do it:

```
 Uri texte = new Uri(@"http://192.168.0.18:18148/Instancename/ODataV4/");
 NAV.NAV x = new NAV.NAV(texte);
 x.Credentials = credentials;
 DataServiceActionQuery funcionini = x.Funcions_TestFunction(param1, param2, param3);
 funcionini.Execute();
```

with the DataServiceQuery ( pages published) I have no problems to pass it, simply add query option:

```
 DataServiceQuery<NAV.Customer> z = x.Customer.AddQueryOption("company", "Mycompany");
 IEnumerable<NAV.Customer> resultat = z.Where(f => f.Type == "something").OrderBy(f => f.Name);//.GetAllPages();
```

sample with postman ( at the end you can see the url parameter: **?company=mycompany** )
[image: Sample with postman]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Insert Company

1. Simplest way: Place `"MyCompany"` the company in the URL:

```
Uri texte = new Uri(@"http://192.168.0.18:18148/Instancename/ODataV4/Company(MyCompany)");
```

2. More elegant: Add the company header to each request for NAV. I prefer the EventHandler `BuildingRequest` to do that:

```
NAV.BuildingRequest += (_, e) => e.Headers.Add("company", "MyCompany");
```

## Sample Code

In the generated NAV class I added the `Credentials` and the `BuildingRequest`. I also added `SendingRequest2` and `ReceivingResponse` for debugging:

```
public NAV(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : base(serviceRoot, global::Microsoft.OData.Client.ODataProtocolVersion.V4)
{
    // generated Code in constructor
    this.ResolveName = new global::System.Func<global::System.Type, string>(this.ResolveNameFromType);
    this.ResolveType = new global::System.Func<string, global::System.Type>(this.ResolveTypeFromName);
    this.OnContextCreated();
    this.Format.LoadServiceModel = GeneratedEdmModel.GetInstance;
    this.Format.UseJson();

    // my additions
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pw", "domain");
    BuildingRequest += OnBuild;
    SendingRequest2 += showRequest;     // for debugging
    ReceivingResponse += showResponse;  // for debugging
}

private void OnBuild(object _, BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.Headers.Add("company", "myCompany");
}

private void showResponse(object sender, ReceivingResponseEventArgs e)
{
    // for debugging
}

private void showRequest(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
{
    // for debugging
}
```

Then you should be able to call your function:

```
var x = new NAV.NAV(new Uri("uri"));
DataServiceActionQuery funcionini = x.Funcions_TestFunction(param1, param2, param3);
funcionini.Execute();
```

My code generation tool generated `DataServiceActionQuerySingle` instead of `DataServiceActionQuery`. I **guess** this depends on how functions are defined in NAV. I call functions like this:

```
var x = new NAV.NAV(new Uri("uri"));
string result = x.FunctionReturningString("test").GetValue();
```

Comment: Hi, ok  "buildingRequest",  this object is the one indicated to call a function? can show me some sample or web that shows his functionality? Tanks

Comment: That's cool man, many tanks!!